# How to keep my code running after an exception is caught (Java)

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write code for a class project that can handle all exceptions and invalid entries from the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    double wallHeight = 0.0;
    double wallWidth = 0.0;
    double wallArea = 0.0;
    double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;

    final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;

    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's height
    try {
        //System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
        do {//wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
            wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            if (wallHeight <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid height");
            }
        } while (wallHeight <= 0);
    } catch (Exception excpt) {
        System.out.println("Invalid height");
        wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
    }

    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's width
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
        wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
        if (wallWidth <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Width");
        }
    } while (wallWidth <= 0);


    // Calculate and output wall area
    wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
    System.out.println("Wall area:  " + wallArea + " square feet");

    // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
    gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
    System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");

}
}
```

The check that I'm trying to pass for the assignment is inputting a string instead of a double for the wallHeight. It prints "Invalid height" but then the program stops running and returns the error. How do I get it to continue running and prompt again for a valid input from the user?

Comment: I think you just need to put your try/catch inside of the do-while loop. Put the try/catch around the method that throws the Exception instead of putting it around the whole do-while no ?

Comment: too much code for a method. try to break into simple methods and then go for exception suppression in the method where its really required.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paint1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double wallHeight = 0.0;
        double wallWidth = 0.0;
        double wallArea = 0.0;
        double gallonsPaintNeeded = 0.0;
        boolean validNumber = false;
        
        final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;
        
        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Prompt user to input wall's height
        do {
        System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
        if (scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
            wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            validNumber = true;
            if (wallHeight >0) {
                wallHeight = wallHeight;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Must be greater than 0.  Try again.");
                validNumber = false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.  Try again.");
            System.out.println();
            validNumber = false;
            scnr.next();
        } 
        } while (!validNumber);
        
        

        // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
        // Implement if-else loops to ensure correct value/type is given
        // Prompt user to input wall's width
        validNumber = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter wall width (feet): ");
            if (scnr.hasNextDouble()) { 
                wallWidth = scnr.nextDouble();  
                validNumber = true;
                if (wallWidth >0) {  
                    wallWidth = wallWidth;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Must be greater than 0.  Try again.");
                    validNumber = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.  Try again.");
                System.out.println();
                validNumber = false;
                scnr.next();
            }    
        } while (!validNumber); 

        // Calculate and output wall area
        wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
        System.out.println("Wall area: " + wallArea + " square feet");

        // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the wall
        gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea/squareFeetPerGallons;
        System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");

    }
}
```

Comment: Use if/else loops inside your do/while loop to ensure variable type/value is what's desired.  Try/catch is another way to do this but I used if/else loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double a = in.hasNextDouble() ; 
        System.out.println(a);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
```

This prevents InputMismatchException from even being thrown, because you always make sure that it WILL match before you read it.

Comment: However, it will prevent input from advancing if no valid double is found, because the token that is there is not consumed.

Comment: @daniu, yes, see my answer for how to solve this problem. You may also upvote if you like...

Comment: @daniu i think the best way to prevent unchecked exception instead of handling them . my answer is conveying that idea only . please refer below link. below link talks about why we should not catch the unchecked exception . https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_unchecked.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Your current method of prompting for input (on `wallWidth` and `wallHeight`) is flawed because you catch an exception which is almost certainly `InputMismatchException` (and then you fail to consume the token that was not a number). I would strongly recommend you **extract** your prompt to another method; something like

```
private static double readWallDimension(Scanner scnr, String dimension) {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            System.out.printf("Enter wall %s (feet):%n", dimension);
            double dim = scnr.nextDouble();
            if (dim <= 0) {
                System.out.printf("Invalid %s%n", dimension);
            } else {
                return dim;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException excpt) {
            System.out.printf("Invalid %s%n", dimension);
            scnr.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `main` method is significantly simpler, invoking that method twice (and both times the exceptions are handled locally).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double squareFeetPerGallons = 350.0;

    double wallHeight = readWallDimension(scnr, "height");
    double wallWidth = readWallDimension(scnr, "width");

    // Calculate and output wall area
    double wallArea = wallHeight * wallWidth;
    System.out.println("Wall area:  " + wallArea + " square feet");

    // Calculate and output the amount of paint (in gallons) needed to paint the
    // wall
    double gallonsPaintNeeded = wallArea / squareFeetPerGallons;
    System.out.println("Paint needed: " + gallonsPaintNeeded + " gallons");
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this response and I'm sure it would work but I also fear it would seem strange and suspicious since a lot of this code uses things that haven't been covered yet in our class. The assignment is specifically looking to test our ability to handle exceptions. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: @DavidConrod You should look closely at the method I have posted; it came from your question and could certainly be *applied* to your current code. Change `return dim;` to `break;` to terminate the loop. Replace the `printf` calls with your existing prompts, and `for(;;)` is the same as `while(true)`. Was there something else you have not yet covered?

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. Could you explain why it won't work the way I have it?

Comment: Oh I see, so I would need to add something that deals with the input that caused the exception. Sorry, I've only been working with Java for a couple months so I'm not too well versed in it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working variant based on your code, with fixes and explanations:

```
    // Implement a do-while loop to ensure input is valid
    // Prompt user to input wall's height
    do { // moved one level up <- enable repeated input until it is valid
        try { // moved one level down <- catch exception where it occurs
            System.out.println("Enter wall height (feet): ");
            wallHeight = scnr.nextDouble();
            if (wallHeight <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid height");
            }
        } catch (Exception excpt) { // generally better: InputMismatchException
            System.out.println("Invalid height");
            scnr.nextLine(); // SKIP THIS INVALID LINE.
            // Otherwise calling nextDouble() only throws the same exception as previously.
        }
    } while (wallHeight <= 0);
```

Note that this should meet the OP. Otherwise:

- If you may introduce new methods in your class project, then extracting the `do - while` to a dedicated method for reading any number input should be the way to go.
- If you would like to avoid handling exceptions, you could use a combination of `scnr.hasNextDouble()` + `scnr.nextLine()` instead. You can read the methods' [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to fully understand what they do.